# PDO Access Query

Tags: sql, pdo

Hi everyone I've some problems with a PDO query in access.

```
$result1 = $database->prepare('SELECT * FROM tblDestinazioni INNER JOIN tblRagioneSociale ON tblDestinazioni.id_cliente = tblRagioneSociale.id_cliente');
//$result1->execute(array(':nrags' => $rag, ':ndrags' => $nuovadest));
$result1->execute();
```

in this way it works, but i have to insert two more conditions... so:

```
$result1 = $database->prepare('SELECT * FROM tblDestinazioni INNER JOIN tblRagioneSociale ON tblDestinazioni.id_cliente = tblRagioneSociale.id_cliente WHERE tblDestinazioni.nome_dest=ndrags AND tblRagioneSociale.nomer=nrags');
$result1->execute(array(':nrags' => $rag, ':ndrags' => $nuovadest));
```

But it doesn't work (It returns to me a wrong result).

Please help me,
Thanks a lot

```
tblDestinazioni:
id_destinazioni INT AUTO_INCREMENT(PK)
id_cliente INT(FK)
nome_dest VARCHAR(30)

tblRagioneSociale:
id_cliente INT(PK)
rags VARCHAR(30)
```

more code:

```
<?php
$db_username = ''; //username
$db_password = ''; //password
$database_path = "Z:\\2017datiW.mdb";
$database = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft AccessDriver(*.mdb)}; DBQ=$database_path; Uid=$db_username; Pwd=$db_password;");
$rag=$_POST["rag"];
$nuovadest=$_POST["nuovadest"];
$result1 = $database->prepare('SELECT * FROM tblDestinazioni INNER JOIN tblRagioneSociale ON tblDestinazioni.id_cliente = tblRagioneSociale.id_cliente');
$result1->execute(array(':nrags' => $rag, ':ndrags' => $nuovadest));
?>
```

Comment: without a proper example with input data and expected results we cannot help. And the point that all the fields name are in italian makes the query even harder to be understood by most of the users here

Comment: Try to replace `ndrags` by `:ndrags` in your query and `nrags` by `:nrags`. So they will be saw as parameters. The `execute` method needs the parameters to be preceded by `:`

Comment: Rewrite the query in English or give us sample data from DB

Comment: I've added more information, sorry but I have to understand how to post because I'm new here